# What's a phrase to capture traffic, road type, weather conditions?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

What is a short phrase that could be used to describe the conditions under which one is driving (traffic, road type, stop-and-go, weather)?  Our product provides a "rating" to consumers of how risky it is based on these factors (and others, for which we have good phrases to name them.  But this particular group of factors is stumping us.  "Conditions", "External factors", "Environment" are too boring and not good for a consumer facing product.

Comment: uncontrollables (noun) ~ [something that cannot be controlled](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uncontrollables)... contingencies ~ [a contingent event; a chance, accident, or possibility conditional on something uncertain](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contingency)

Comment: They're generally referred to as "travel conditions."

Comment: I would normally say "driving conditions" or "road conditions".

Comment: @Benjamin Harman & Hot Licks ~ She said that *conditions* was too boring and specifically wants a buzz word/phrase

Comment: @V0ight - Possible synonyms of "condition":  status, situation, state, standing, circumstance, character, outline, specification, disposition, prospect, influence, category, order, classification, quality.

Answer (score 1):

**contingency**, **contingencies**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contingency)

> 2. a [conditional, uncertain, possible] event; a chance, accident, or possibility conditional on something uncertain

---

[The Illustrated London News](https://books.google.com/books?id=JI0cAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22driving+contingency%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22equipment+for%22)

> "*The smooth, six-cylinder engine gives ample power for any **driving contingency**. Steering, braking, acceleration are superb, owners say, and petrol consumption is surprisingly low. Springing is smooth, upholstery luxurious, the equipment for comfort and convenience splendidly complete.*"

[Principles of information retrieval](https://books.google.com/books?id=-KFkAAAAMAAJ&q=%22driving+contingency%22&dq=%22driving+contingency%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy-K_C2_HNAhVDxYMKHbDZD-Q4ChDoAQgfMAE)

> *"We could perhaps design a machine which drives (or learns to drive) a car with a standard transmission. We might not say this machine knows how to drive. it has no options for action. Every **driving contingency** has to be anticipated by its designer and planned for. There are no questions for it to ask, for it could not behave differently than it does."*

[Michigan Manufacturer and Financial Record](https://books.google.com/books?id=zecTAQAAMAAJ&q=%22driving+contingency%22&dq=%22driving+contingency%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy-K_C2_HNAhVDxYMKHbDZD-Q4ChDoAQgyMAU)

> *"These headlights adequately answer the demand for every conceivable **driving contingency** — country driving, country passing, city driving, city passing and parking. These five variations are available in the new Cadillacs."*

[Engineering and Mining Journal Press: Vol.114](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z8U6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22road+contingencies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjp9C53fHNAhWMxYMKHWLbDyU4KBDoAQgkMAI#v=onepage&q=%22road%20contingencies%22&f=false)

> *"By the elimination of certain mechanical handicaps we can gradually approach an “ideal atmosphere”; at any rate, one in which less attention need be paid to car performance and more to **road contingencies**."*

[Diseases of a Gasolene Automobile: And how to Cure Them : a Practical Book ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=6k4EAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%22road+contingencies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYhIro3fHNAhUm6YMKHTpABZk4MhDoAQg5MAY#v=onepage&q=%22road%20contingencies%22&f=false)

> *"Despite the fact that the space available for tools is usually limited, with a judicious selection of tools, nearly all emergencies or **road contingencies** can be successfully met."*

[Motorcycles from the inside out: and how to keep them right side up](https://books.google.com/books?id=T7gZwa3yZjUC&q=%22road+contingencies%22&dq=%22road+contingencies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYhIro3fHNAhUm6YMKHTpABZk4MhDoAQhFMAg)

> *"The enduro motorcycle saddle is usually large enough to allow significant fore and aft rider movement, to allow easy front or rear weight bias for **off-road contingencies.**"*

[The Motor Car Journal, Volume 11](https://books.google.com/books?id=KWIfAQAAMAAJ&q=%22road+contingencies%22&dq=%22road+contingencies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYhIro3fHNAhUm6YMKHTpABZk4MhDoAQhKMAk)

> *"The vehicle, which is painted a brilliant or-inge, is fully equipped to meet all **road contingencies**."*

[Zen Driving](https://books.google.com/books?id=fZrqOZnrfqAC&pg=PT52&dq=%22driving+contingencies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVraLo3vHNAhUm2IMKHZMJCEEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22driving%20contingencies%22&f=false)

> *"Natural-self, the experience and awareness needed to handle all **driving contingencies**, never gets acknowledged, much less fully developed. Instead of driving in control of all situations, we fall hostage to them."*

[The Autocar: A Journal Published in the Interests of the Mechanically Propelled Road Carriage, Volume 105](https://books.google.com/books?id=0wEnAAAAMAAJ&q=%22driving+contingencies%22&dq=%22driving+contingencies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgvIaT3_HNAhVq9YMKHX3kCeY4ChDoAQgkMAI)

> *"...in front of the shiny, red bonnet is a picture which lights up to present various **driving contingencies**, so that pupils can take appropriate action."*

[Keystone Motorist, Volumes 26-27](https://books.google.com/books?id=9JI7AAAAMAAJ&q=%22driving+contingencies%22&dq=%22driving+contingencies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgvIaT3_HNAhVq9YMKHX3kCeY4ChDoAQgyMAU)

> *"The reason for this generally accepted opinion is that the rear wheels are the ones that propel the car and should, therefore, have the best grip on the road to meet various **driving contingencies**, particularly in order to prevent skidding."*